# Two pages for the same resource - ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, scope, activeadmin

Currently I have `User` model, which is registered in `user.rb` as a new resource for ActiveAdmin. Generated page displays all users with scopes (`all`/`journalists`/`startup_employees`). Now I want to create another page for the same resource, and the same scopes, but there should be only records with `waiting` field set to `true` (and the previous page should displays only this with `:waiting => false`). How could I do that? I know I could do that with filters, but I need two separate pages, with two links in menu.

// SOLUTION

It was even easier than advices (thanks guys!):

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :as => 'Waitlist User' do
  menu :label => "Waitlist"

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      User.where(:waitlist => true)
    end
  end

  # code

  scope :all
  scope :journalists
  scope :startup_employees
end
```

---

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      User.where(:waitlist => false)
    end
  end

  # code

  scope :all
  scope :journalists
  scope :startup_employees
end
```

Comment: what should be the file names in this case

Answer (score 5):

STI (**Single table inheritance**) can be used to create multiple "sub-resources" of the same **table/parent** model in `Active admin`

1. Add a "type" column in user table as a string
2. Add this to `User` model to mirror waiting field with type field

   ```
   after_commit {|i| update_attribute(:type, waiting ? "UserWaiting" : "UserNotWaiting" )}
   ```
3. Create the new models `UserWaiting` and `UserNotWaiting`

   ```
   class UserWaiting < User
   end
   class UserNotWaiting < User
   end
   ```
4. Create `Active Admin` resources

   ```
   ActiveAdmin.register UserWaiting do
   # ....
   end
   ActiveAdmin.register UserNotWaiting do
   # ....
   end
   ```
5. You can run a first-time sync in console

   ```
   User.all.each {|user| user.save}
   ```

..............

Another way could be to skip the type column (steps 1,2 and 5) and solve the rest with scopes.

1. Step 3 and 4 above
2. Then create the scopes

   ```
   #model/user.rb
   scope :waiting, where(:waiting => true)
   scope :not_waiting, where(:waiting => false)
   ```
3. Scopes in `Active Admin`

   ```
   #admin/user.rb
   scope :waiting, :default => true

   #admin/user_not_waitings.rb
   scope :not_waiting, :default => true
   ```

Just make sure the other scopes in these two pages are also filtered on waiting/not_waiting

Answer (score 1):

you could use a parameter to distinguish the cases and render different actions depending on the parameter:

```
link_to users_path(:kind => 'waiting')
```

and in the users_controller.rb

```
def index
  if params[:kind]=='waiting'
    @users= Users.where(:waiting => true)
    render :action => 'waiting' and return
  else
    # do your other stuff
  end
end
```

then put your new, different page (partial) in app/views/users/waiting.html.erb

If you want to use a different layout for this page add the layout parameter to render:

```
render :action => 'waiting', :layout => 'other_layout' and return
```