# Rails ActiveAdmin : Multiple Index Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, activeadmin

I understand that ActiveAdmin supports multiple index pages if the index pages are of different types (table, grid, block, blog), but I need to have two index table pages. I tried

```
index :as => :table do
...
end

index :as => :table do
...
end
```

but the index page only displays the first table. Is there a way to display both tables and rename the tabs?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActiveAdmin: how to add second custom index table page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662981/activeadmin-how-to-add-second-custom-index-table-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `two index table` pages will not work as you expected as Active_admin will always pick the first match of `index :as => :table`.

In order to achieve the required result i.e., two index table pages, what you can do is, 
keep one as index table page and for other create a `custom index`.

Refer to **[Multiple Index Pages](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html)** section and **[Create your own index page](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/create-an-index.html)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's a working example over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662982/214702

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this.

[Two pages for the same resource - ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546502/two-pages-for-the-same-resource-activeadmin/16559759#16559759)

For example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :as => 'Waitlist User' do
end
```

This way you dont need to create a custom index page.