# ActiveAdmin: how to add second custom index table page

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

Users of some admin need to have two table views of, say, a model `Bar`: default one they already have and an additional new one with different set of columns.

The setting is such:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bar do
  # …
  index do
    column :name
    column :phone
    column :address
  end
  # …
```

It's expected to be as easy as adding another `index` block as in:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bar do
  # …
  index do
    column :name
    column :price
    column :bartender
  end

  index name: 'location' do
    column :name
    column :phone
    column :city
    column :country
  end
```

and then just get the additional tab somewhere.

As you may guess it is not that simple. ActiveAdmin nows nothing about the imaginary `index name:` attribute and just selects the first `index` block silently ignoring the second `index` block.

ActiveAdmin documentation shows a way to [add second/third/etc index page](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html) with ease but of a different kind:

```
index as: :grid do |bar|
  link_to(image_tag(bar.photo_path), admin_bar_path(bar))
end
```

Nice, but how to add a duplicate of the index table view with different columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a trick.

As show before ActiveAdmin's `index` method allows the `as:` argument with the type of the index coded as symbol (ATM, one of these: `:block`, `:blog`, `:grid` and `:table`). Alongside with symbols (which are just shortcuts for some internal AA classes) it's possible to pass any Ruby class:

```
index as: CustomTableIndex do
  # …
end
```

---

Here is the code for the solution.
Four things to do for our new table index page:

1. create a subclass of `ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsTable`
2. define a class method `index_name` in the subclass with a name of the new index page
3. pass the new class to the `index` method
4. add a i18n translation for the new tab button (if necessary)

in `app/admin/bars.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bar do

  # …

  # 1.
  class MyLocationIndex < ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsTable
    # 2.
    def self.index_name
      "bars_location"
    end
  end

  # 3.
  index as: MyLocationIndex do
    column :name
    column :phone
    column :city
    column :country
  end

  # …

end
```

in `config/locales/admin.yml`:

```
en:
  # …
  active_admin:
    index_list:
      bars_location: "Locations"
```